# How is gelatine sold in U.S. grocery stores?

Tags: gelatin

I'm interested in trying a [recipe from Alton Brown for marshmallow](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/homemade-marshmallows-recipe/index.html). I'm not sure what exactly *"3 packages unflavored gelatin"* refers to.

How much gelatine (in weight) is included in a standard package of gelatine in the U.S.? And what [bloom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28test%29)<sup>*</sup> would that be?

Probably has no bearing, but is that likely to be powdered or leaf gelatine?

<sup>* Actually not sure what bloom is used for gelatine from Swedish stores. Awaiting a reply from Dr. Oetker's customer service on that point :-)</sup>

Comment: From experience, the Oetker-brand powdered gelatin packets you can get in Hungary are totally identical to the Knox-brand powdered gelatin packets you can get in the US. I don't imagine the Swedish ones are any different, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The packs typically contain the equivalent of 15mL of gelatine and are in powder form.  Each pack is measured to set 500mL or two cups of liquid.  As far as weight, it feels like about 6-7 grams of gelatin.

The dominant brand seems to be [knox](http://www.knoxgelatine.com/basics.htm).

[image]

As for the bloom, I'm not really sure as I haven't seen it published on the label.  However, I *have* actually made marshmallow using the same Alton Brown recipe and it seemed pretty tolerant.  So slightly different bloom should be fine.  I also deviated with the corn syrup and didn't use it (I avoid corn).  The end result was still awesome.

Comment: what did you use as a corn syrup substitute?

Comment: @GdD recall Alton saying something about needing invert sugar, so I made [invert sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_sugar_syrup#Inverting_sugar) by adding cream of tartar or lemon juice to real sugar, not sure which.  The wikipedia article describes.

Answer (score 4):

Knox doesn't publish the bloom strength but it's 225 so you know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are really asking is how to convert US recipes based on packets to use gelatin sheets.

Per [Modernist Pantry](http://www.modernistpantry.com/gelatin-sheets-gold.html):

> You can successfully substitute sheet gelatin for powdered gelatin in
>   any recipe by using the following scaling.
>
> 1 (0.25 oz.) envelope granulated gelatin = 1 tablespoon powdered
>   gelatin = 3 sheets leaf gelatin.

Comment: You can buy either powdered or sheet gelatine in the shops here; I only wanted to know which one to go for. The real sticking points for me are how much a standard package contains, and whether the blooms for US and EU gelatine are similar (comments from Marti suggest that they are).

Comment: Well, the quantity info is above, but I have no idea on the bloom--I have never seen this published on consumer grade gelatin.