# how much powdered gelatin to one gelatin leaf?

Tags: gelatin

Some recipes call for a number of gelatin leaves, but since I use powdered gelatin I'd like to know the conversion rate/scaling.

Answer (score 13):

According to [Modernist Pantry](http://www.modernistpantry.com/gelatin-sheets-gold.html) and thanks to [SAJ14SAJ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/35393/18726):

> You can successfully substitute sheet gelatin for powdered gelatin in
> any recipe by using the following scaling.
>
> 1 (0.25 oz.) envelope granulated gelatin = 1 tablespoon [(15 ml)] powdered
> gelatin = 3 sheets leaf gelatin.

and so one sheet of leaf gelatin would correspond to ~1 teaspoon (5 ml) of powdered gelatin.

and a bit extra info from [Modernist Cuisine](http://modernistcuisine.com/2012/12/5-dessert-tips-from-modernist-cuisine-at-home/)

> Gelatins are measured by what is called their Bloom strength (usually labeled as bronze, silver, gold, or platinum). Knox brand has a bloom strength of 225. If you are making a recipe (not just one of ours, but any recipe), be it a Jell-O wreath or a pâté, you can use a different Bloom strength than what the recipe calls for, but you’ll have to do a little math. You can convert the recipe to use whatever gelatin you have on hand if you know the weight (MA) and Bloom strength (BA).
>
> For gelatin A, you can find the equivalent weight of gelatin B (MB) with a Bloom strength of BB by using the formula MB = MA × BA ÷ BB. For example, if a recipe calls for 2.6 g of Knox gelatin, you could use 3.7 g of silver gelatin, which has a Bloom strength of 160 (2.6 × 225 ÷ 160 = 3.7). To make a vegetarian panna cotta, we substitute 0.8 g agar and 0.65 g xanthan for the 4.3 g gelatin the recipe normally calls for.